# how to convert a dictionnary which contains an in memory model instance into a string using json.dumps

Tags: python, django

```
import json 
dict = {'username': u'Toto', 'staffTitle': u'Mr', 'staffName':     u'Toto', 'company': <Company: Test1>, 'qualifications': [{u'dateObtained': u'2017-11-22', u'qualificationId': 1048,}

convert_to_string = json.dumps (dict)
sa_ = sanitize_data(conver_to_string)
back_to_dict = json.loads(sa_)


def sanitize_data(dirty_data):

    clean_data = re.sub('(<0x\w*>)|\s',"", dirty_data)
    return clean_data
```

So what i'm trying to achieve something.To convert as dict into a string using json.dumps then use my made function to sanitize and remove non_ascii characters and convert it back to a dict and save it.
Because ,there is an in memory instance ('company': ) part of the dict. I'm having an error, the dumps does not work. How can i sort out this and being able to convert this dict into string and process the data? Any ideas?

Comment: By implementing a *serializer*: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar: this will not work, since `json.dump` will simply nog recognize a "vanilla Python" type and error (otherwise all items are converted to textual representation, but there would be no way back).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, that's right. I was thinking wrong. thanks for your comment.

Comment: so how could we get that right ...i've tried str(). Backthe way back does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments by others, `json.dumps()` will not work out of the box on python classes or Django models instances. Django REST framework is very good if you want to expose your data to a REST API, it would let you expose just the fields you want in a maintainable way.

If this is for an internal usage, Django has [a serialization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/) built-in:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", Company.objects.get(name="test"))
```

This is simple for a quick serialization, but probably not suitable to expose your models to the external world via a REST API, DRF is a much better choice in this case.